# Angular2: Serve a different homepage if the user is logged in

Tags: angular, routes

I want the base url `/` to show different content based on whether the user is logged in:

- Not logged in: Show `LandingPageComponent`.
- Logged in: Show `DashboardComponent`.

And just to be clear, `/` should not redirect or change the url, it should just decide which content to show.

This is a fairly common thing to do (for example, Twitter does it.) But the problem is, I am new to Angular, and so far I haven't found a straightforward way to do this. I know how to route different paths to different components, but I don't know how to conditionally route a single path to multiple components. What is the best way to go about this?

Please try to keep any answers beginner-friendly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you share your router configuration..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Above can be done by below steps

Step1: By default show one HomeComponent which has below html code



Step2: In the constructor/ngOnInit(depending on the situation) of HomeComponent decide use has logged in or not.

Note: isLoggedIn is an Observable. i.e isLoggedIn: Observable;

HomeComponent template will be as below

```
<template [ngIf]="isLoggedIn | async">
<dashboard></dashboard>
</template>
<template [ngIf]="(!isLoggedIn | async)">
<login-page></login-page>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's pretty simple to achieve this in NG2. You must just follow the principles:

Firstly, you must know you need to use Guard for your route which is four different guard types:

> CanActivate to mediate navigation to a route.
>
> CanActivateChild to mediate navigation to a child route.
>
> CanDeactivate to mediate navigation away from the current route.
>
> Resolve to perform route data retrieval before route activation.
>
> CanLoad to mediate navigation to a feature module loaded
>   asynchronously.

In order to register that, you should provide in in NgModule Provide:

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [AuthService, UserEditGuard, UserEditGuard2],
...
})
```

Before I move on I would mention that Guards can be implemented in different ways, but after all it really boils down to a function that returns either **Observable**, **Promise** or **boolean**.However, while you are declaring your routes you should use canActivate

```
export const USER_ROUTE: Routes = [
      {path: 'edit', component: UserEditComponent, canActivate: [UserEditGuard],canDeactivate: [UserEditGuard2]}
    ];
```

then define your class for this Guard, an example should be as follow:
Note that a guard needs dependency injection capabilities. Therefore, define a class for login authentication seems necessary.

```
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service'; // assuming you have auth service

import {Observable} from "rxjs";

export class UserEditGuard implements CanActivate {

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot,private authService: AuthService): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
      return confirm('you are not logged in!');
      // for example you can have your service authenticate
      // return this.authService.isLoggedIn().map(e => {
      //  if (e) {
      //      return true;
      //  }
      // }).catch(() => {
      //    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      //    return Observable.of(false);
      // });
  }

}
```

for more information, [I recommend reading angular.io documents](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard).

I hope I could give you an insight about how you can protect your route and redirect to other routes.

UPDATE:

You may have this solution for your request as we discuss in comments.

```
export class AppComponent {
               // Include authService in the constructor to gain access to the API's in the view
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
}
```

then in template :

```
  <div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn()">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h2> You need to Logging In to see your dashboard</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn()">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h2>View Private Dashboard</h2>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" routerLink="/dashboard">my dashboard</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

it will update DOM based on the result of *ngIf. You can add this to your homepage, but you also need to protect private routes.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this is used to redirect the user if they are not logged in. As stated above, I do not want the homepage to redirect.

Comment: Although you need to protect other routes anyway, you can do this, just have a *ngIf to DOM, for instance *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" I am updating my answer.